# Making a ListBox item editable using DataTemplate or DataTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datatemplate, datatemplateselector

In my application, I've DayView window which contains listbox with some entries in it. I've declared two datatemplates for this window. DefaultDataTemplate and EditableData Template. Also I've used DataTemplateSelector.
I want to edit my listbox entries when I click on edit button.

xaml code:

```
<!-- Default DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultDataTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StartTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding StopTimeBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="60"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectNameBinding}" Background="Transparent" Padding="0" Margin="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="130"/>  
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>

        <!-- Editable DataTemplate -->
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EditableDataTemplate">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="596">
                <!--<ComboBox x:Name="ClientComboBox" SelectionChanged="ClientComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=clientList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name" SelectedItem="{Binding ClientNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="145"/>-->
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ClientNameBinding,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="145"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding ApplicationNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="90"/>
                <xctk:TimePicker Value="{Binding StartTimeBinding, ElementName=MainWin, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="100" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
                <xctk:TimePicker Value="{Binding StopTimeBinding, ElementName=MainWin, Mode=TwoWay}" Format="Custom" FormatString="hh:mm tt" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" Width="60" EndTime="11:59:0"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding TaskNameBinding}" Background="Yellow" Padding="0" Margin="0" BorderThickness="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ProjectComboBox" SelectionChanged="ProjectComboBoxChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=projectList, ElementName=MainWin}" SelectedValuePath="_id" DisplayMemberPath="_name"  SelectedItem="{Binding ProjectNameBindingClass, Mode=OneWayToSource}" Width="130" Background="Yellow" BorderThickness="0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>


        <!-- DataTemplate Selector -->

        <l:DayViewListDataTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"
          DefaultDataTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultDataTemplate}"
          EditableDataTemplate="{StaticResource EditableDataTemplate}"/>
```

C# code for Editing listbox items:

```
private void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Harvest_TimeSheetEntry item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            if (item.isSynced)
            {
                if (listBox1.ItemTemplate == (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate"))
                {
                    DataTemplate tmpl = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("EditableDataTemplate");
                    listBox1.ItemTemplate = tmpl;
                    this.EditButton.Content = "Done Editing";
                }
                else
                {

                    DataTemplate tmpl = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("DefaultDataTemplate");
                    listBox1.ItemTemplate = tmpl;
                    this.EditButton.Content = "Edit";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Globals._globalController.harvestManager.postHarvestEntry(item);
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Entry posted");
            }

        }      
    }
```

C# code for DataTemplateSelector:

```
public class DayViewListDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate DefaultDataTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate EditableDataTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item,DependencyObject container)
    {
        Harvest_TimeSheetEntry entryToPost = item as Harvest_TimeSheetEntry;
        if (entryToPost.isClientEditable == true)
        {
            return EditableDataTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return DefaultDataTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to change mode from DefaultDataTemplate to EditableDataTemplate when click on edit button.
Following problems occurs:
1.When converted to EditableDataTemplate, Existing text does not displayed.
2. When saving edited changes, TimePicker retain old values. 
3. Debugger shows error as - Both ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are set. DataTemplateSelector is ignored.

I don't understand, how to use DataTemplateSelector here in edit code, if possible please explain.

Comment: Show code of DataTemplateSelector and show complete XAML.